# How to make a road terrain for unity game?

Tags: unity, terrain, low-poly, asset-creation

im making a FP game in low poly style. I want to make some terrains for my game, with roads, trees, rocks, buildings and e.t.c. Unity terrains are not as good as i thought. They allow a good tool for placing multiple objects (like tree-to-sprite tools, trees mesh copy for perfomance), but the terrain building tool itself is very poor, so i cant use 3d terrain, because there will be no great tools for placing surroundings.

So my plan is - make low poly mountains, trees, rocks in Blender, then make a simple terrain with hills in unity and just place my surrounding objects on it. I have some troubles, for example - roads. I have a road elements, and by connecting & banding them i can get a really nice road. But how can i make a road on Unity's terrain?

For example it could be useful to export unity terrain as a 3d mesh to Blender, then make my roadways and export them in Unity.

Answer (score 3):

You could concider making the terrain and road in blender and use those in unity. Blender has the power to generate heightmaps from objects, in case you dont want to use the object itself.